# "Quemcunque miserum videris nominem scias"

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation

Can someone help me find the meaning of this phrase?

> Quemcunque miserum videris nominem scias.

Comment: It's a slightly garbled version of line 463 from Seneca the Younger's tragedy *Hercules furens*: *nominem* should actually be *hominem* (*quemcunque* would also more commonly be spelled *quemcumque*, though it isn't wrong as is).

Answer (score 4):

@cnread is correct. The [original phrase](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2007.01.0003:card=457&highlight=Quemcumque+miserum%2C) comes from Seneca's *Hercules Furens*, and reads:

> Quemcumque miserum videris hominem scias

There are [many](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Quemcunque+miserum+videris+hominem+scias%22+seneca) translations available, not all of them equivalent. For instance, [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EZJoSq45EPQC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22Quemcunque+miserum+videris+hominem+scias%22&source=bl&ots=cAj5ELztnj&sig=9vXodrWZamLDqwO1NNTU33h5f-c&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyz8Si9ubaAhXGkCwKHc5qDIoQ6AEwBHoECAAQSA#v=onepage&q=%22Quemcunque%20miserum%20videris%20hominem%20scias%22&f=false) (about Latin phrases and their translations) translates as:

> whenever you see a fellow creature in distress, remember that he is a man

Notice there seems to be no text containing the phrase you mention (which doesn't make much sense, actually). The version with *quemcunque* is the motto of the [Royal Life Saving Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Life_Saving_Society_UK), founded in 1891.

[image]

According to [Wiki](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RLSS_Bronze_Medallion.jpg), it translates as:

> Whomever you see in distress, recognize his humanity.

However, according to the [website of the society itself](http://www.rlsscommonwealth.org/about/), it translates as:

> Whomsoever you see in distress, recognise in them a fellow human being

As you can see, there is no a unique translation (not surprising, as far as I can tell), but you get a clear idea of what the phrase means.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case ***nominem*** was an intentional/ smart replacement for ***hominem,***

The new version is more media-savvy than Seneca's original;

> Quemcunque miserum videris nominem scias.

Whoever you may see in distress...

> *miser, miserum (accusative)* could mean unhappy, or unfortunate, wretched, pitiful, distressed, in distress.  (Smiths Dictionary 1895)

...let me make them famous, you know.

> *nomino* **II** make famous, to nominate.

(and *scias* could be those 'knowing women.')

Or it could have been an attempt to say (this was my first thought): *nomen scias,* 'Get to know their name.'  That would be the sociable response to someone miserable.

Comment: It is indeed possible that it was an attempt at wordplay, but *nomen* is neuter so the accusative would be simply *nomen*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It would also perhaps be better to have *cuiusviscunque,* *genitve.*